# Sharing a search bar header between React Navigation tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native application using React Navigation. In this app I have a TabNavigatator with a few tabs—two of which share a custom header component with a search bar.

Here are the relevant snippets of the tab classes:

```
export default class ScreenOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {filter: ''};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({filterOne: this.filter});
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      header: (<MainHeader filterOne={params.filterOne} />)
    };
  }

  filter = (q) => {
    // . . .
  }

  . . .
}
```

The other tab is essentially identical:

```
export default class ScreenTwo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {filter: ''};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({filterTwo: this.filter}); //line A
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      header: (<MainHeader filterOne={params.filterOne} />)
    };
  }

  filter = (q) => {
    // . . .
  }

  . . .
}
```

And the header itself:

```
export default class MainHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  filter = (q) => {
    this.setState({text: q});
    // this.props.filter(q);
                // previously the passed filter props shared a name,
                // but that didn't work
    if (this.props.filterOne) {
      this.props.filterOne(q);
    }
    if (this.props.filterTwo) {
      this.props.filterTwo(q);
    }
  }

  . . .
}
```

The text in the search remains between tabs, so I don't think the header is being recreated.

If I comment out "Line A", I get ScreenOne's filter functioning, but with the line in place, only ScreenTwo's filter works, and One's errors out as undefined.

Do I have the wrong approach to this? I tried splitting MainHeader into HeaderOne and HeaderTwo, but the second setParams is still removing the first filter declaration. Am I missing something?